# Delete files in s3 Bucket older than 14 days using Powershell

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-s3

I am trying to write a script to delete files older than 14 days using PowerShell, but my script deletes every file created in my s3 bucket.

Is there anything wrong in my script?

```
#set a bucket name
$bucket = "neb-migration/ms-sql/"

#set the expiration date of files
$limit_date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-14)

#get all the files
$files = aws s3 ls "$($bucket)"

#extract the file name and date
$parsed = $files | ForEach-Object { @{ date = $_.split(' ')[0] ; fname = $_.split(' ')[-1] } }

#filter files older than $limit_date
$filtred = $parsed | Where-Object { ![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.date) -and [datetime]::parseexact($_.date, 'yyyy-MM-dd', $null) -ge  $limit_date }

# #remove filtered files
$filtred | ForEach-Object { aws s3 rm "s3://$($bucket)$($_.fname)" }
```

Comment: Consider using a lifecycle policy to do this for you.

Comment: BTW you seem to be using >= $limit_date which seems wrong. Surely you want objects that are older.

Comment: You should be looking at `-le  $limit_date` for files older than your target date.

Answer (score 1):

Try this script

```
$date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-14) 
$olderThan = $date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
$bucketName = "your-bucketName-here"
$data = aws s3 ls s3://$bucketName/ --recursive 
ForEach ($line in $data)
{   
    $createDate=$line| ForEach-Object { $_.split(' ')[0] }
    if ($createDate -lt $olderThan)
    {
        $fileName=$line| ForEach-Object { $_.split(' ')[-1] }           
        if ($fileName -ne "")
        {
            aws s3 rm s3://$bucketName/$fileName
        }   
    }
    else
    {
        echo ("File Not Found")
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).